# How to load Resources in view level

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resources, view

Even thow it's the most comfortable way to merge all resources on application level it can also cost performance by loading all resources at startup. A better approach is to load only often used resources and load the other on view level.

How to load Resources in view level?

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a resource dictionary and then merge the resource dictionary at the UserControl or Window level. For example:

```
<UserControl ...>
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="NameOfYourDictionary.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```